# How to check if all items in an array of strings are key in a NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I feel like there should be a way to use a lambda to check if all keys in a NameValueCollection are in an array of strings. For instance, lets say you have:

```
NameValueCollection nvc; // passed in parameter
string[] requiredFields = new string[] { 
    "copy_ugp", "copy_ep", "copy_et", "copy_eg" 
};
```

and I want to be able to do something like:

```
if( somelambda which is false if any item in required fields is not in nvc)
{
} else {
   throw new MissingParamsException();
}
```

I think there should be an elegant solution without having to create a bool which is set to true, and then iterate over the requiredFields and set it to false if a key is missing.

Comment: This is more related to LINQ than Lambda expression. You don't need a Lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Habib's solution is really good. Other way to go would be

```
if (requiredFields.All(requiredField => collection[requiredField] != null))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) to find differences between `requiredFields` and your keys in `NameValueCollection` and then use `Enumerable.Any` like:

```
if (requiredFields.Except(nvc.AllKeys).Any())
```